# Why "rake gems:install" showing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install Fedena, a ERP for educational institutions. Fedena is based on Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to install it on a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS. At one stage of the installation I've to give this command

```
sudo rake gems:install
```

When I'm giving this command. Its showing me the following error and I can't proceed further

```
root@education:~/fedena/projectfedena-fedena-84b5ad9# sudo rake gems:install
Fedena requires i18n gem version 0.4.0 to be installed.Run gem install i18n -v 0.4.0
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/root/fedena/projectfedena-fedena-84b5ad9/Rakefile:8
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Why I getting this error? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The rubygems that come with all Linux distros are broken beyond repair. Start over with `rvm` or `rbenv` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you suggested when I'm giving "rvm rake gems:install". It is saying that, "Please note that `rvm rake ...` was removed, try `rake gems:install ` or `rvm all do rake gems:install ` instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )
". Please suggest what can I do now?

Comment: are you using 'sudo'? you can't use it with rvm.

Comment: No, I'm not using "sudo". I'm using the "rvm rake gems:install" command, but I'm entering this command with root access. So, without using sudo, I'm getting all privileges.

Comment: rvm works entirely inside your user account. With "root access", you have different paths & such. What do `which gem` or `which ruby` return?

Comment: "which gem" returns "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/gem"

Comment: When I'm giving "rvm all do rake gems:install" it says that "Missing the Rails 2.3.5 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.5 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
". What can I do?

Comment: Why are you using Rails 2.3 with Ruby 2?